# how to an increment the index when using "objectAtindex" for dictionaries inside an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

So we have a plist which features an array of dictionaries. The Array is allCategories and it currently features two dictionaries acting as questions. Each dictionary has a set of strings. The goal is so that when you press the button it will check whether it is correct and if so increment currentQuestion and setTitle and picture for the new dictionary in allCategory array. This, however doesn't work and we don't know how to fix it. So far it recognizes that it is the correct question and that it should change it, however nothing is displayed. If we make currentQuestion = 1 and remove the currentQuestion++ and we click the button it works perfectly. We want it to increment based on whether it is correct though.

```
 - (IBAction)showPic
{


    NSDictionary *picturesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Property List" ofType:@"plist"]]; //sets the proper plist file

    allCategory = [picturesDictionary objectForKey:@"AllCategory"]; //Sets the array allCategory

    currentQuestion++; //There are currently 2 dictionaries acting as the questions.
    NSDictionary *QuestionNumber = [allCategory objectAtIndex:currentQuestion];    answerKey = [QuestionNumber objectForKey:@"correctAnswer"];
    correctAnswer = [QuestionNumber objectForKey:answerKey]; //the two lines above determine what the correct answer is based on the plist.

    if([self.buttonOutlet.currentTitle isEqualToString:correctAnswer]) //this is where the comparison is made.
    {

        NSLog(@"currentQuestion:%d", currentQuestion);
        //the button titles should change to the next dictionary in allCategory, however it wont change.
        self.Label.text = @"This is working";

    }
    else if(currentQuestion != 0){
        [self.buttonOutlet setTitle: [QuestionNumber objectForKey:@"A"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.buttonTwo setTitle: [QuestionNumber objectForKey:@"B"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.buttonThree setTitle: [QuestionNumber objectForKey:@"C"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.buttonFour setTitle: [QuestionNumber objectForKey:@"D"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: [QuestionNumber objectForKey:@"fileName"]];
        [imageHolder setImage:img];
        self.Label.text = @"This is correct";



    }
    else {
        self.Label.text = @"This is not correct";
    }

}
```

this is the plist

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>AllCategory</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>fileName</key>
            <string>gta.jpg</string>
            <key>A</key>
            <string>gta</string>
            <key>B</key>
            <string>COD</string>
            <key>C</key>
            <string>LOL</string>
            <key>D</key>
            <string>Watchdogs</string>
            <key>correctAnswer</key>
            <string>A</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>fileName</key>
            <string>LOL.jpg</string>
            <key>A</key>
            <string>Watchdogs</string>
            <key>B</key>
            <string>La Noir</string>
            <key>C</key>
            <string>Dota 2</string>
            <key>D</key>
            <string>fifa</string>
            <key>correctAnswer</key>
            <string>D</string>
        </dict>
       </array>
     </dict>
    </plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove

`int currentQuestion = 0;`

and set it somewhere outside of the `IBAction` otherwise each time you hit the button it will reset `currentQuestion` to 0.

Why do you create a key for the answer

```
answerKey = [QuestionNumber objectForKey:@"correctAnswer"];
correctAnswer = [QuestionNumber objectForKey:answerKey];
```

you should just be able to access it direcltly

```
correctAnswer = [QuestionNumber objectForKey:@"correctAnswer"];
```

and get rid of the answerKey

Comment: ok so I took that off and declared currentQuestion in the .h file as an int, however I still need to initialize it as 0 correct? Where should I do that?

Comment: @user3705117 in `viewDidLoad` for example, it just need to be out side of the function scope

Comment: Just tried that still doesn't work. Nothing is being displayed. Should i keep the currentQuestion++ inside the if statement though?

Comment: @user3705117 yes keep it there but move it to the last line of the if block and add display `self.Label.text = @"This is the correct answer";`

Comment: the label changed to "This is the correct answer" however nothing else is changing. Not sure why that is?

Comment: @user3705117 what is supposed to change?

Comment: all the button titles and the image. If the currentQuestion is incremented by one then a new dictionary is being looked at and that means there are new values for the titles and filename. The plist shows the next dictionary. This is why i was wondering whether the ++ should go in the beginning or at the end

Comment: @user3705117 I expanded onmy answer

Comment: its because it wouldn't access it properly. The value for correctAnswer in the plist is 'A', however it wouldn't be able to properly compare because the value it will compare it to is 'GTA' therefor we need to compare the key with the value for correctAnswer. The if statement is working fine though since it is changing the label. When i removed the currentQuestion completely and just manually incremented the value. the picture changed and so did the titles. It just makes no sense that when I use currentQuestion it stops working.

Comment: `NSLog(@"currentQuestion:%d", currentQuestion)` I suggest you to log it to the console something is not normal

Comment: 2014-07-21 21:05:45.117 test[2639:60b] currentQuestion:1
this is the output and it is correct. Still no display.

Comment: @user3705117 move `NSDictionary *Question = [allCategory objectAtIndex:currentQuestion];` right below `currentQuestion++;`

Answer (score 0):

This really comes down to a matter of variable scope.  A property defined in the .h file is globally visible to all methods in your class, and will be visible to any external classes that subclass or use your class.  Those are public properties that are visible so that others who may re-use your method in the future can pass the information into your method without necessarily having to know what the internals do.  You can also have an interface section at the top of your .m file.  This is for methods that like the .h file have global scope within the class, but they are not visible to other classes using your class.  Both of these types of properties are accessed in your methods by using the self. prefix.  A variable defined inside of a method is only visible inside that method and does not require the self. prefix. Local variables have a lifespan of the method they are in.  Each time you re-enter the method a new instance of that variable is created.

In your case, currentQuestion is defined as a local variable inside your method.  Each time you come into it, you create the variable and initialize it to zero.  By doing what meda said and moving it outside of your method, it is a global property and can be seen by all methods inside your class.  When you initialize it in viewDidLoad or another method that initializes early in the viewcontrollers life, you set it to zero once and then you increment it like you are doing in the if statement of your method.

Moving it to the bottom of the if statement won't really help any since you don't seem to reference it anywhere in the if statement (unless I missed one), but moving it to the bottom does eliminate any confusion around which things are being displayed inside the if statement.  So it's good from that perspective.

Try this:

```
#import "exViewController.h"

@interface exViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger currentQuestion;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageHolder;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonOutlet;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonTwo;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonThree;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonFour;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSDictionary *picturesDictionary;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *allCategory;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSDictionary *QuestionNumber;

@end

@implementation exViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // we have to initialize the screen with the first question.
    // There isn't any reason to re-initialize these every time you pick an answer do
    // do it up here in viewDidLoad
    self.picturesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PropertyList" ofType:@"plist"]]; //sets the proper plist file

    self.allCategory = [self.picturesDictionary objectForKey:@"AllCategory"]; //Sets the array allCategory


    // Initialize currentQuestion to 0
    self.currentQuestion=0;

    // I put the statements to display the question into another method so they wouldn't
    // have to be put in the code multiple times.  Makes it easier to maintain.
    [self displayQuestion:self.currentQuestion];
}

// display question takes one arguement, the value for currentQuestion  so it's going
// to display the question associated with whatever index is.
- (void) displayQuestion:(NSInteger) index
{
    // get questionNumber like you did before, but using index which we passed into this method.
    self.QuestionNumber = [self.allCategory objectAtIndex:index];
    self.picturesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PropertyList" ofType:@"plist"]]; //sets the proper plist file

    self.allCategory = [self.picturesDictionary objectForKey:@"AllCategory"]; //Sets the array allCategory

    [self.buttonOutlet setTitle: [self.QuestionNumber objectForKey:@"A"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonTwo setTitle: [self.QuestionNumber objectForKey:@"B"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonThree setTitle: [self.QuestionNumber objectForKey:@"C"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonFour setTitle: [self.QuestionNumber objectForKey:@"D"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: [self.QuestionNumber objectForKey:@"fileName"]];
    [self.imageHolder setImage:img];
}

//This was your old showPic method.  I added the sender parameter being sent to it.
// it points to the button that was clicked.
- (IBAction)showPicture:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSDictionary *QuestionNumber = [self.allCategory objectAtIndex:self.currentQuestion];
    NSString *answerKey = [QuestionNumber objectForKey:@"correctAnswer"];
    NSString *correctAnswer = [QuestionNumber objectForKey:answerKey]; //the two lines above determine what the correct answer is based on the plist.
    NSLog(@"answerkey=%@",answerKey);
    NSLog(@"Correctanswer=%@",correctAnswer);
    NSLog(@"sender=%@",sender.description);

    //remember we are now passing in the address of the button that we clicked so we
    //can just checking sender(the button).titleLabel.text and see if it's equalto the correct answer.

    if(![sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:correctAnswer])
    {
        // wrong answer
        NSLog(@"currentQuestion:%d", self.currentQuestion);
        self.Label.text = @"Wrong Answer";
    }
    else {
        // right answer go to next question
        self.currentQuestion++;

        // make sure we don't go outside our bounds past the last question.
        if(self.currentQuestion<[self.allCategory count]) {
            self.Label.text = @"This is correct!! Next question";
            // call the method to display the question using the incremented currentQuestion.
            [self displayQuestion:self.currentQuestion];
        } else {
            self.Label.text = @"Correct answer end of test";
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: well after doing all the changes suggested by Meda, I believe it is incrementing properly, however the button outlet titles and the images are not displaying the new data. If it is actually incrementing then clicking the button should put the new values in for all the titles and the image.